# Symfony 3.4.4 + FOSUserBundle + Sonata Admin Bundle - User list filtering by role

Tags: fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4

I need:

- If the user logged in Sonata Admin is SUPER_ADMIN, see all users
- If the user logged in Sonata Admin is ADMIN, that **NO** see the SUPER_ADMIN

It is to know how, within UserAdmin.php, modify the query by filtering by ROLE

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this is my solution:

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery('list');

    if (!$this->isSuperAdmin()) {
        /** @var \Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQuery @query */
        $query
            ->where("o.roles NOT LIKE '%ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN%'");

    }

    return $query;
}
```

And, with this function, verify if user is SUPER_ADMIN or not:

```
private function isSuperAdmin() {
    $isUserSuperAdmin = false;

    $actualUserRoles = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getRoles();

    if (in_array("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN", $actualUserRoles)) {
        $isUserSuperAdmin = true;
    }

    return $isUserSuperAdmin;
}
```